# How to define the name of my model class in my case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a migration created table in database with name "**number_updated**", can I have the model name:

```
class NumberUpdated < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Why I ask this question is because by convention, rails use **plural** name for database table and singular name for model, for example, DB table name is "**Cars**" and model class name is "**Car**". But in my case, how the name should be?

In rails, is every table name in database **MUST end with 's'** to indicate it is a plural???

Comment: In fact, pluralization of table names are handled by the `Inflector` class which follows proper rules and exceptions in english. If you have a model named `Ox`, its default table name would be `oxen`, not `oxs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NumberUpdate` model class to better reflect Rails conventions.

```
class NumberUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

and

```
create_table :number_updates do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this as well

```
class NumberUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base    
   set_table_name "number_update"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Models are objects, which means they are represented by nouns. You can't look at a row in a database and say "This is a number updated".

As Simone points out, it makes more sense to say "This is a number update", and then it becomes a table of "number_updates"

Comment: Ok, thanks, while, what I would like to know is that CAN I keep using "number_update" for table name and using "NumberUpdate" as my model class name, more like to question on the rails convention:), but I will use the convention, thank you!